# How to handle PIN in android aplications, using appium javascript

Tags: appium, appium-android

During the test flow I need the user to enter the phone pin, is there any way to perform this action through appium?

I've tried using 'await driver.unlock()', but it only serves to unlock the device when it's locked.

I couldn't find anything in the appium documentation.